# compare two array and return id if array match

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter. I have two table job_post and snapshot.I have written query to fetch data from above table like :

Query1 :

```
select skill from snapshot where user_id = 1
```

and it gives and array like :

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [skill] => 1,2
    )
)
```

Query2 :

```
select emp_id,skill from job_post
```

and this query return array like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [emp_id] => 10
        [skill] => 1,2,3
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [emp_id] => 10
        [skill] => 3,12,13
    )
)
```

Now, I want to match these to array. If **query1** skill match with the **query2** skill then its return emp_id. So how can I get that emp_id?

**Note :** Partical match with query1 and query2

Comment: Full match or partial match?

Comment: @Sougata partial match

Comment: Please show us what you have tried in order to achieve this

Comment: Ok. SO have you tried anything?

Comment: No, because i dont have any idea about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store below query's response in a variable lets say in $mySkill.

```
select skill from snapshot where user_id = 1;

"select emp_id,skill from job_post where concat(',',skill,',') like '%,".$mySkill.",%'"
```

Alternative:  you need to explode $myskill & then need to create or condition dynamically.like:

```
$arrmyskill = explode(",",$mySkill); 
foreach($arrmyskill as $skill )
{ 
   $str .=" or concat(',',skill,',') like '%,".$skill.",%' ";
} 
$finalqry = "select emp_id,skill from job_post where concat(',',skill,',') like '%".$mySkill."%'" .$str;
```

Comment: Here I have a problem. it find skill as 1 and 2 in job_post table.If both skill are match then it will return.

Comment: Here I have skill as 1 den it match with 11 so its gives wrong result and i remove % then it does not give any output that match with exact 1. so what can i do?

Comment: I am very sorry, missed the comma...Please check my edited post

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will  solve your problem

```
<?php 
$arr1 = array('skill'=> '1,2,3');
$arr2 = array(array('emp_id'=>1,'skill'=> '1,2,3'),array('emp_id'=>1,'skill'=> '1,2,4'));
foreach($arr2 as $key => $val)
{
    if($val['skill']== $arr1['skill'])
    {
        echo 'Matched Id :'.$val['emp_id'];
    }
}
?>
```

this will output :

```
Matched Id :1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use single SQL query to JOIN both tables? If any skill(s) matches, the query will give you needed emp_id with matched skills in addition.

```
SELECT
    j.emp_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(j.skill) AS skills
FROM
    job_post j
    INNER JOIN `snapshot` s ON s.skill = j.skill
WHERE
    s.user_id = 1
GROUP BY
    j.emp_id
```